# Trying to exclude a portion of an xPath

Tags: xpath

I have looked through several posts about this, but have failed to apply the principles used to get the result I desire, so I'm going to just post my specific problem.

I am building a Google Sheet that enables the user to pull up Bible verses.
I have it all working, however I am running into an issue with a hidden element being pulled into my text().

FUNCTION:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.biblestudytools.com/ESV/Numbers/5-3.html", 
           "//*[@class='scripture']//span[2]//text()")
```

RESULT: You shall put out both male and female, putting them outside the camp, that they may not defile their camp, 1in the midst of which I dwell."

You can see the "1" that is showing up before the word "in"

I have found the xPath that pulls only that "1"

```
//*[@class='scripture']//span[2]//sup//text()
```

I am trying to remove that "1" from the text.

HELP PLEASE!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a predicate to the end to exclude text nodes that are inside `sup` elements:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.biblestudytools.com/ESV/Numbers/5-3.html",
           "//*[@class='scripture']//span[2]//text()[not(ancestor::sup)]")
```

This will retrieve only the text nodes that are not inside a `sup` element, but it will still result in having the verse spread out across two cells, because there are two text nodes. You can rectify this by wrapping this expression in a `JOIN()`:

```
=JOIN("", IMPORTXML("http://www.biblestudytools.com/ESV/Numbers/5-3.html", 
                    "//*[@class='scripture']//span[2]//text()[not(ancestor::sup)]"))
```

Comment: So, I'm also having issues with some scripture that are eliminating sections within quotes using your function. Check this URL:
http://www.biblestudytools.com/NIV/Mark/4-39.html

thoughts?

Comment: @geoffschultz I can have a look later today.

Comment: This is what I currently have as my function:

=regexreplace(JOIN(CHAR(10), IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@class='scripture']//span[2]//text()")),"\n", "")

Comment: @GeoffSchultz Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much. I just couldn't figure out that [not] part - exactly what I needed.